# Flutter _TypeError (type '(int) => void' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => void')

Tags: flutter, dynamic, typeerror

I think to be familiar with flutter dynamics, but here at runtime I get an error:

```
class SelectMonthDialog<int> extends StatefulWidget {
  final int _month;
  final void Function(int month) _onItemSelected;
  final void Function() onCancel;
  const SelectMonthDialog(this._month, this._onItemSelected, this.onCancel,
      {super.key});

  @override
  State<SelectMonthDialog> createState() => SelectMonthDialogState();
}

class SelectMonthDialogState extends State<SelectMonthDialog> {
  late int _month;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _month = widget._month;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        content: NumberPicker(
          value: _month,
          minValue: 1,
          maxValue: 12,
          onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _month = value),
          textMapper: <int>(number) =>
              DateFormat(DateFormat.MONTH).format(DateTime(0, number)),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => widget._onItemSelected(_month),
            child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.ok,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => widget.onCancel(),
            child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cancel,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
          ),
        ],
      );
}
```

[image]

Why is it recognized as dynamic?

EDIT:

If I add `implicit-casts: false` to the `analysis_options.yaml` on `DateTime(0, number)` I see that `number` is dynamic, and so `SelectMonthDialog`s variables. Why?

What does the following mean?

`The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'`

Comment: chnage _onItemSelected function's parameter type dynamic to int eg. _onItemSelected(int data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've actually defined it as dynamic by writing

```
class SelectMonthDialog<int> extends StatefulWidget {
```

By writing `<int>` here you are making it a dynamic type. Your class is actually identical to

```
class SelectMonthDialog<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T _month;
  final void Function(T month) _onItemSelected;
  final void Function() onCancel;
  const SelectMonthDialog(this._month, this._onItemSelected, this.onCancel,
      {super.key});

  @override
  State<SelectMonthDialog> createState() => SelectMonthDialogState();
}
```

It's not the normal `int` type because of this. You need to simply remove the `<int>` because I think in your situation you wouldn't want this. So simply write

```
class SelectMonthDialog extends StatefulWidget {
```

Comment: Thanks, the dialog was generic and I forgot to remove it when I refactored it to a non generic class.